Using nGinx to serve static files via Reverse Proxy
I was working on nGinx, trying to use it as a reverse proxy. Currently I have setup a nGinx as a service that is running on port 80 and receiving all the request from client. Then I'm running multiple application as a docker container exposed on different port. Below is the config sample of nGinx file.
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  server_name;
        location /app1{
                proxy_pass http://ip:3006/;
        }
        location /app2{
                proxy_pass http://ip:3007/;
        }
        location /app3{
                proxy_pass http://ip:3009/;
        }

Each app have their own static files, and worked perfectly when I tried to access them using port.
Requirement is that user will send request in this format
http://ip/app1/media/dummy.wav 
And then nGinx should re route the request to their container, based on the path.
Problem with above solution is that when user is trying to access css, js or other files it is sending the request to http://ip/stylesheets/application.css, here /app1 or /app2 is removed. In the referrer header it is showing it properly.
referer: http://ip/app1/ but still request was sent to url without path.
Have seen multiple solution for the same, but there is one constraint in all those solutions that all the static files are avlb in single folder, here in this usecase, each applications have their own static files and resources.

The best and simplest solution is to have different domains. app1.example.com, app2.example.com etc. Otherwise, you have to configure your app to use /app1/... for static files. Depending on app it could be from as simple as one line in config to nearly impossible.

You need to set up the root URL in your applications properly, so that they generate proper URLs. There is nothing in nginx that can reliably address the issue.
